# How to display a variable by symbols

Tags: maxima

Suppose I have

```
b:2;
c:3;
a:b+c;
```

Is there a way to display the *definition* of `a`, that is to display `b+c` instead of `5`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have stated the problem, no, because after the assignment, `a` doesn't have any association with `b + c` (only with the numerical value which was assigned).

However, you can rephrase the problem so that you can recover the right-hand side of the assignment. For example:

```
kill (a, b, c); /* remove any existing values */
b : 2;
c : 3;
a : '(b + c);
  => c + b
''a;
  => 5
a;
  => c + b

kill (a, b, c);
a : b + c;
  => c + b
b : 2;
c : 3;
''a;
  => 5
a;
  => c + b
```

In both cases, `b + c` is not substituted by the numerical values when it is assigned to `a`, either by preventing evaluation (first example) or by assigning before `b` and `c` are given numerical values. Finally here's another approach which avoids assigning numerical values to `b` and `c`:

```
kill (a, b, c);
a : b + c;
  => c + b
subst ([b = 2, c = 3], a);
  => 5
a;
  => c + b
```

I think this last method, which uses `subst`, is preferable, because the other approaches use the quote-quote operator `''` which is a little too subtle and therefore has an effect which might be surprising.